# Remove spaces before and after parentheses without using lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Im trying to remove the space after and before closing parenthesis using regex, the problem is that Safari not supporting my solution, is there any alternative for using "lookbehind" functionality?

My string for example:
`check IN [ "[hello world]*" ] OR host IN (  abc,123)`

Im expecting to get:
`check IN ["[hello world]*"] OR host IN (abc,123)`

My current solution:
`(?<=[([])\s+|\s+(?=[)\]])`

Comment: *"... after and before closing parenthesis..."* Your example involves removing spaces after **opening** parentheses...?

Comment: You _can't_ solve this with pure regex, because the brackets/parentheses may be nested.  You need some kind of parser here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Normally, of course, that's absolutely true. But in this case, I think they're processing `(___` and `___)` in isolation, so I think nesting isn't an issue.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly..

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:

1. You **always** want to remove any spaces after a `(` or `[` and any spaces before a `)` or a `]`, and
2. You won't have `(`, `)`, `[`, or `]` inside text literals that you want to leave unchanged *(this is really just a subset of #1, but I thought it worth calling out specifically, as it's a big assumption)*

...then I don't think nesting is an issue and we can do this with a regular expression. And I don't think you need lookaround at all:

```
const result = str.replace(/([\[(])\s+|\s+([\])])/g, "$1$2");
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
// after opening ( or [ −−−−−−−−/          |
// before closing ) or ] −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−/
```

The trick there is that we use two captures, and then use both in the replacement; one of them will always be `""` while the other will be `"("`, `"["`, `")"`, or `"]"`.

Example:

```js
const str = `check IN [ "[hello world]*" ] OR host IN (  abc,123)`;

const result = str.replace(/([\[(])\s+|\s+([\])])/g, "$1$2");
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
// after opening ( or [ −−−−−−−−/          |
// before closing ) or ] −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−/

document.getElementById("before").textContent = str;
document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
```

```html
Before:
<pre id="before"></pre>
After:
<pre id="result"></pre>
```